# How to Progressively highlight a chunk of text using jquery/js/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

The effect can be seen live at [Webdesignerdepot.com](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/) . When you hover over the title of a post the title highlights progressively also when you remove the cursor from the title before the animation is complete the highlight rolls back to its original state.

I tried animating the background color, but the problem that I faced was background color extended the whole div even when text didn't completely  filled the div.

I have been thinking of adding an extra div with a z-index less than that of the text and then animating its width, but it would fail since text can extend more than one line. If the resulting effect is to be achieved with the same process it will result in multiple divs making the program really complex.
I couldn't think of any other way of achieving this.
Any other workarounds/techniques I can use?

Comment: Can't you check the source code of the site?

Comment: @Terry I analysed the source code for a while, but am pretty sure the effect is achieved using js, being a beginner at Javascript I found it overwhelming plus there are no comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use javascript console or firebug or something like that and it's really easy to get a website styles.

CSS

```
a {
  background-size: 200.22% auto;
  -webkit-background-size: 200.22% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 200.22% auto;
  background-position: -0% 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #ddd 50%);
  transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.5s ease-out;
}

a:hover {
  background-position: -99.99% 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<a>something</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help nada, but it fails when a single line of text spans more than one lines. How to take care of that?

Comment: sorry my English is reallt bad :P please put me an html example of that (when it fails)

Comment: Oops my bad I tested it on the h1 tag rather than the a tag. Thanks it works now